# Quartz processes not exiting, causing memory overflow

Tags: java, quartz

I am running a process from inside a Quartz scheduler by calling it's `main` method. This process runs fine but spawns some non daemon processes which keep running even after `main` method has returned and therefore with each new process the Scheduler spawns, the memory is never freed.

If I put a `System.exit(1)` at the end of `main`, and call it independently, it exits normally. But when it is called from the scheduler, it causes the whole app to exit.

Is there any way I can explicitly kill the process once the method has returned?

Comment: What is "memoty overflow"? OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: @VladimirShefer yes